# So where do we go now for library recommendations?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Stackoverflow used to be a good place for me to find a library for my specific requirements. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923500/lightweight-and-portable-regex-library-for-c-c?lq=1

Apparently, that is now considered "off topic". But these questions still exist, and people still want answers to them. The StackExchange format is also much better suited to this than, say, wikipedia. Yes, you will sometimes get opinions, but even opinions can be useful.

So, is there a different StackExchange sites where we can ask and look for these questions instead?

Comment: We have the new [Software Recommendations SE site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but do follow their [ground rules](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.